# Python: Adding a column of the same value

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

I have a tab-delimeted file that contains 3 columns. I would like to add a new first column of just same number 1.

inputfile is

```
a 3 6
b 3 5
c 3 5 
d 8 4
```

This is what I would like to have for my outputfile:

```
1 a 3 6
1 b 3 5
1 c 3 5
1 d 8 4
```

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import csv  
f=open('inputfile.txt', 'r+')
t=[]
for line in f.readlines():
    t.append('\n')
    t.append(1)
    f.writelines(t)
```

However, I am getting an error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py.py", line 6, in 
    sys.stdout('inputfile.txt', 'w')
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable

Comment: `sys.stdout` is used for output stream. It's not a function.

Comment: You'd want to open your output file the same way you opened your input. `fout = open('outputfile.txt', 'w')` and `fin=open('inputfile.txt', 'r+')` Also, why are you trying to read and write from your input file?

Comment: File objects in python used by the interpreter for representing the open files. And `sys.stdout` object initialized to file objects corresponding to the interpreter’s standard output. It's just a regular text file like those returned by the `open()` function. Read more https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open both files and write to it, concatenating a `1` and tab `\t` to each line in a running list. Then output list to new file:

```
f1 = "Input.txt"
f2 = "Output.txt"

t = []
with open(f1, 'r') as txt1:
    for rline in txt1:       
        t.append("1\t" + rline)

with open(f2, 'w') as txt2:
    for i in t:
        txt2.write(i)

#1  a   3   6
#1  b   3   5
#1  c   3   5
#1  d   8   4
```

Alternatively, to avoid use of a list (but requires appending to file with `'a'`):

```
with open(f1, 'r') as txt1:
    for rline in txt1:       
        rline = "1\t" + rline

        with open(f2, 'a') as txt2:
            txt2.write(rline)
```

And even further suggested by @JonClements that avoids the overhead of opening/closing file with each line:

```
with open(f1) as txt1, open(f2, 'w') as txt2:
        txt2.writelines('1\t' + line for line in txt1)
```

Comment: You can change your later example to be: `with open(f1) as txt1, open(f2, 'w') as txt2` then make your entire statement block `txt2.writelines('1\t' + line for line in txt1)` - this'll avoid the overhead of opening/closing the file each line of the input...

Comment: Just to note - it's not a list-comp - it's a generator expression :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sys module for the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
input_file = open('input.txt', 'r+')
for line in input_file.readlines():
    line = line.split(" ")
    line.insert(1, str(1))
    line = (" ").join(line)
    output_file.write(line)

input_file.close()    
output_file.clsoe()
```

cat output.txt gives output:

```
a 1 3 6
b 1 3 5
c 1 3 5
d 1 8 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want nothing else you can skip csv module and just prepend each line in a file, like this:

```
open('out.txt', 'w').writelines(["1\t" + line for line in open("in.txt")])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you exactly what your desired output shows:

```
fin = open('inputfile.txt', 'r+')
fout = open('outputfile.txt', 'w')
t=[]

for line in fin.readlines():
    t.append('1 ' + line)

fout.writelines(t)
```

Comment: OP states *I have a tab-delimeted file* (so your `'1 ' + line'` will be prepending a value to the first column - not creating a new one) - also - readlines will read the entire file into a list first, you're then append then to another completely new list - you can just loop over `fin` directly and write line-by-line.